# Way to find the total Memory Used by a program in Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way yo find total memory used by a process and whole program in Python Kivy .
I.e. some way by which i can find out :

1. total memory used by the program?
2. objects active and using how much memory ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) is a memory profiler for Python. Use it like this:

```
>>> from guppy import hpy
>>> h = hpy()
>>> h.heap()
```

The output will be something like this:

```
Partition of a set of 1449133 objects. Total size = 102766644 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 985931  68 46300932  45  46300932  45 str
     1  24681   2 22311624  22  68612556  67 dict of pkgcore.ebuild.ebuild_src.package
     2  49391   3 21311864  21  89924420  88 dict (no owner)
     3 115974   8  3776948   4  93701368  91 tuple
     4 152181  11  3043616   3  96744984  94 long
     5  36009   2  1584396   2  98329380  96 weakref.KeyedRef
     6  11328   1  1540608   1  99869988  97 dict of pkgcore.ebuild.ebuild_src.ThrowAwayNameSpace
     7  24702   2   889272   1 100759260  98 types.MethodType
     8  11424   1   851840   1 101611100  99 list
     9  24681   2   691068   1 102302168 100 pkgcore.ebuild.ebuild_src.package
<54 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

This is "basically a snapshot of what's reachable in ram". I didn't do much Kivy development so I never got around to profiling, but I think this should work.

See:

- [Getting started with Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/heapy_tutorial.html)
- [How to use guppy/heapy for tracking down memory usage](http://smira.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/heapy.html)